# R: Examine to see if a Datatable is subset of another Datatable

Tags: r, datatable, subset, rbind

How I can check to see if a `data table` is **subset** of another `data table`, regardless of the `row` and `column` order? 
 For instance, imagine someone `rbinded` the `DT_x` and `DT_y` with removing the `duplicate` and created `DT_Z`. Now, I want to know how I can compare `DT_x` and `DT_Z` and get the result which show/state that the `DT_z` is a `subset` of `DT_Z`?

as very simple example:

```
 DT1 <- data.table(a= LETTERS[1:10], v=1:10)
 DT2 <- data.table(a= LETTERS[1:6], v=1:6)
 DT1
    a  v
 1: A  1
 2: B  2
 3: C  3
 4: D  4
 5: E  5
 6: F  6
 7: G  7
 8: H  8
 9: I  9
10: J 10

DT2
   a v
1: A 1
2: B 2
3: C 3
4: D 4
5: E 5
6: F 6
```

I am sure `all.equal(DT1, DT2)` will not answer my question.

Comment: Are they keyed? If you can trust `a` as a key, then `all(DT2$a %in% DT1$a)`. If you need to check both columns' equality then you could do `nrow(DT2) == nrow(merge(DT1, DT2, by = intersect(names(DT1), names(DT2))))`. If you don't lose rows on an inner join then it is a subset of the larger dataset (assuming no duplicates).

Comment: @Gregor, like you said it works if there would not be any duplicate, How about the case that there would be a duplicate during the inner join?

Comment: De-dupe the tables first and check the unique versions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `data.table`'s `fintersect()` and `fsetequal()`:

```
is_df1_subset_of_df2 <- function(df1, df2) {
  intersection <- data.table::fintersect(df1, df2)
  data.table::fsetequal(df1, intersection)
}
```

The first line picks the elements in `df1` that exists in `df2`.
The second line checks if that set is all of `df1`.